# sound effect library

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, effects

I'd like to apply effects like pitch/reverb/delay/distortion on a recorded sound.

Do you know a sound FX library for iOS that could do that (opensource if possible) ?
thanks
Louis

Comment: i have the same task.. if you are done then can you plz guide me how to do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS provides the Audio Units framework, which has the effects you mentioned. Take a Look at the [Audio Units hosting guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Also, this is a really solid library for interacting with Core Audio: http://theamazingaudioengine.com/. It supports FX as well. Plus, you can still go down to the Core Audio layer if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

For something more unique you can try SpectrumWorx SDK library from www.littleendian.com/developers, it's a collection of sound effects which can also be easily chained in any number of ways to provide for some really unique sounds, especially for games.

Answer (score 0):

iOS sound efx library I don't know.
For PC, you can try [GAudio library](http://www.geek-audio.org/)